# Can the Federal Government Revoke Statehood?

Tags: united-states, constitution, statehood

Is this possible? Texas v. White says that states cannot unilaterally secede, but not that they cannot be kicked out. The Constitution (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Admission_to_the_Union#Text)
says that states cannot be admitted or formed from the territories of one or more states without Congress and the state legislatures agreeing, but it does not say anything about revoking statehood. Could Congress vote to either expel states from the country or demote them back into territories?

Comment: Related: https://politics.stackexchange.com/q/43716/26455

Answer (score 6):

> Could Congress vote to either expel states from the country or demote them back into territories?

With the state's consent, yes.  Article 5 of the constitution provides

> that no State, without its Consent, shall be deprived of its equal Suffrage in the Senate.

Comment: If it's no longer a state then it is not a state being deprived of its equal suffrage.

Comment: Depriving a state of its statehood deprives it of its equal suffrage in the senate, so the fact that it can't be deprived of its equal suffrage in the senate without its consent means that it cannot be deprived of statehood without its consent.

Comment: If there’s a law that says that employers have to provide employees with paid sick leave, does that mean that you cannot ever fire employees?

Comment: @Alex of course not, but the analogy is not on point. Paid leave is not a protection of employee status; it is a benefit. A better analogy is that of US citizenship. A US citizen cannot be deprived of US citizenship involuntarily, even though doing so would mean that the person, no longer being US citizen, no longer enjoyed that protection. Or, in the employment analogy, your argument would be like an employer firing someone for protected conduct such as performing jury duty and then arguing that the fired person enjoys no protection against dismissal because the person is not an employee.

Comment: But in the case of jury duty, the firing took place while the person was protected. In the case of de-stateing, the very question being asked is whether there is a protection against being de-stated.

Comment: @Alex the protection exists at all times, regardless of whether it is the subject of a question.  In all three cases, the protection exists because of the protected entity's status, and the protection precludes the loss of that status.  Rules of legal interpretation require us to avoid interpretations that deprive provisions of law of any meaningful effect.  Saying that a protection against change in status has no effect because the change in status removes the protection violates this rule of interpretation.

Comment: @phoog You're begging the question by saying his analogy is incorrect because one is a "benefit" and the other is a "protection against change in status". His argument is exactly that there's no reason to assume article 5 is intended as a "protection" of statehood itself. It's in the article about constitutional amendments, so the more direct interpretation is that an amendment changing the equal representation in the Senate requires unanimous approval among states, instead of approval from 3/4 the states like other amendments. This more plain reading is not devoid of meaningful effect at all.

Comment: Under that interpretation (which seems reasonable to me), it protects states from suddenly having all the responsibilities of being a state, without the equal suffrage in the Senate, but it doesn't protect them from not being part of that country at all. Just like a law requiring sick leave protects someone from suddenly having the responsibilities of an employee but without the right to paid sick leave, but it doesn't protect one from not being an employee at that company at all.

Comment: @phoog I’m not saying “that a protection against a change in status has no effect because the change in status removes the protection”. As mentioned in my previous comment, such a change in status would be invalid since the protection existed at the time of the attempted change. What I am saying is that in the case of states, we don’t know if statehood is a protected status in the first place. If it is not, then a state can be removed from the union. The fact that states have certain rights that can’t be deprived doesn’t imply that a state can’t be removed entirely.

Comment: Just like employee rights don’t imply that employees can’t be fired (unless there is a specific law that says they can’t be fired, as in the jury duty case).